# How to read console output in VS2022 C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I want to build an appliction which can pack all console output to a .txt file. How do I build?
For example, when I execute below code:

```cpp
int main()
{
    system("dir");
    return 1;
}
```

And result will be returned in console:

```
 Volume in drive D is 新增磁碟區
 Volume Serial Number is XXXX-XXXX

 Directory of D:\test\VS2022\ConsoleApplication1

01/06/2024  11:26 AM    <DIR>          .
01/06/2024  11:18 AM    <DIR>          ..
01/06/2024  11:26 AM               840 ConsoleApplication1.cpp
01/06/2024  11:18 AM             1,458 ConsoleApplication1.sln
01/06/2024  11:18 AM             6,647 ConsoleApplication1.vcxproj
01/06/2024  11:18 AM               992 ConsoleApplication1.vcxproj.filters
01/06/2024  11:18 AM               168 ConsoleApplication1.vcxproj.user
01/06/2024  11:26 AM    <DIR>          x64
               5 File(s)         10,105 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  1,685,313,208,320 bytes free

D:\test\VS2022\ConsoleApplication1\x64\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe (process 10272) exited with code 1.
To automatically close the console when debugging stops, enable Tools->Options->Debugging->Automatically close the console when debugging stops.
Press any key to close this window . . .
```

I want to store above to a text file. Please help to make a simple way. Thanks.

Comment: `system("dir > name-of-text-file");`

Comment: Since you tagged your question with ```c++``` and ```visual-c++```, do the following: ```std::system("dir >> output.txt");```

Comment: Note that `system` is only very rarely an appropriate tool—it doesn’t work well with computed commands (or, here, output file names), `^C`, or environment variables.